# Where to find digitized old papers on the internet?

Tags: reference-request, online-resources

Following Murphy's law for the published material:
"The paper you need is too old to be in the arXiv, it is not in any online database which your institution has subscription to, and... it not even in the library!!!"
I really need

Z. Ran. On Subvarieties of Abelian Varieties. $Invent. Math.$ **62** (1981) p. 459--479.

Is there anyone that could help?

Comment: www.emani.org usually works. Look at

http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=PPN356556735_0062&DMDID=DMDLOG_0029

Comment: Thanks Francesco! This was really helpful. Thanks again!

Comment: No longer relevant (answered in comments).

Comment: @DanielMoskovich: I think the underlying general question is where to find old papers online, and this question is *still* relevant.

Comment: I hear #icanhazpdf is very popular...

Comment: It seems that www.emani.org no long works.

Comment: Some reasonable advice concerning searching for papers can be also found in the answers to this question
[Finding a paper](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/40762). Some of the posts [linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/40762) might be of interest, too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suppose the question is "How can I find old papers?" ... (so old that they are not on-line).

If it is "not even in the library" ... then see a librarian.  He/she can get it by interlibrary loan.

Comment: True, but not always works with great efficiency. Once I got a scanned version that was almost unreadable...   
Furthermore I knew there was a digitalized version of the paper, only I had to pay in order to gain access...

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it is worth mentioning that several important journals have been digitized by [GDZ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_for_Retrospective_Digitization). It is one of reasonable places where to look for older papers. (If you can't find it through the subscription of your institution.)

Here is [list of mathematical journals](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/en/dms/colbrowse/?tx_goobit3_search%5Bextquery%5D=%28ismets%3A1%29%20AND%20docstrct%3Aperiodical&tx_goobit3_search%5Border%5D=0&tx_goobit3_search%5BDC%5D=mathematica&tx_goobit3_search%5Bdefault%5D=default&tx_goobit3_search%5Borderfield%5D=bytitle&tx_goobit3_search%5Blink%5D=0) available at GDZ.

In fact, [Google Scholar search](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=%22On%20Subvarieties%20of%20Abelian%20Varieties%22) finds [several versions](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=8852907370558724045&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5) of the paper mentioned in the question. One of them is [eudml link](https://eudml.org/doc/142784) which links further to GDZ.

Several other reasonable possibilities are mentioned in the answers to this question: [Finding a paper](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/40762).